# How to send welcome email with reset password link in Magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.4, password

I want to create a customer account in `Magento 2.4` from cron. And I want to send a welcome email with a reset password link.

**I have found a few articles that helped me to create a customer account. But didn't find any solution for sending a welcome email with a reset password link on a newly created customer account.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for sending reset password emails.

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
) {
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function sendCustomMail()
{

            $email = 'YOURCUSTOMEREMAILADDRESS'; 

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                $this->session->setForgottenEmail($email);
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please correct the email address.'));
            }

            try {
                $this->customerAccountManagement->initiatePasswordReset(
                    $email,
                    AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET
                );
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                // Do nothing, we don't want anyone to use this action to determine which email accounts are registered.
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $exception,
                    __('We\'re unable to send the password reset email.')
                );
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($this->getSuccessMessage($email));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template area="frontend" file="customersendemail.html" id="custom_reset_password" label="Customer Reset Password Custom" module="VendoreName_ModuleName" type="html"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/email**

**customersendemail.html**

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Account Created - Reset Your Password"}}  @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$customer.name}}</p>
<p>{{trans "Welcome to"}}{{trans "%store_name" store_name=$store.frontend_name}}.</p>

<table class="button" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="inner-wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword/',[_query:[token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank">{{trans "Set a New Password"}}</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>{{trans 'Thank you for your registration. '}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Cron**

**CronClassName.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Cron;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor;

class CronClassName
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customer;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $customerRegistry;
    protected $dataProcessor;
    protected $_customerRepository;
    protected $_mathRandom;
    protected $_accountmanagement;

    public function __construct(
        .................................................................
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $accountmanagement,
        \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        .................................................................
    ) {
        .................................................................
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
        $this->_accountmanagement = $accountmanagement;
        $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        $this->senderResolver = $senderResolver ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SenderResolverInterface::class);
        .................................................................
    }

    public function createCustomer($data, $websiteId, $emailTemplate)
    {
        $data =  "array of customer Data";
        $emailTemplate = "custom_reset_password";

        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $checkCustomer = $this->customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($data['id']);
        } else{
            $checkCustomer = $this->customer->create();
        }
        if (!$checkCustomer->hasData()) {
            try {
                $createCustomer = $this->customer->create();
                $createCustomer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                $createCustomer->setEmail($data['email']);
                $createCustomer->setFirstname($data['f_name']);
                $createCustomer->setLastname($data['l_name']);
                $createCustomer->setGroupId($data['group_id']);
                $createCustomer->save();

                /* Send Email TO Customer */
                $emailSendStatus = $this->sendEmailToCustomer($createCustomer, $emailTemplate);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $msg = 'Something went wrong when creating customer.';
            }
        } else {
            $msg = 'Customer Already Created.';
        }
    }

    public function getStoreId($websiteId)
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getWebsite($websiteId)->getDefaultStore()->getId();
    }

    public function sendEmailToCustomer($customer, $emailTemplate)
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId($customer->getWebsiteId());
        $customerEmailData = $this->getFullCustomerObject($customer);
        $templateParams = [];
        $templateParams['customer'] = $customerEmailData;
        $templateParams['store'] = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);

        $sender = \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY;

        $from = $this->senderResolver->resolve(
            $this->scopeConfig->getValue($sender, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId),
            $storeId
        );

        $customerName = $customer->getFirstname() . " " . $customer->getLastname();

        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplate)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
                ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($customer->getEmail(), $customerName)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->logger->info($customer->getEmail() . ' : Email Send Successfully.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($customer->getEmail() . ' : Something went wrong when sending email');
        }
    }

    public function getFullCustomerObject($customer)
    {
        $mergedCustomerData = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());
        $customerData = $this->dataProcessor
            ->buildOutputDataArray($customer, CustomerInterface::class);
        $mergedCustomerData->addData($customerData);
        $customerName = $customer->getFirstname() . " " . $customer->getLastname();
        $mergedCustomerData->setData('name', $customerName);
        $tokenVal = $this->getToken($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getWebsiteId());
        $mergedCustomerData->setData('rp_token', $tokenVal);
        return $mergedCustomerData;
    }

    public function getToken($email, $websiteId)
    {
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->get($email, $websiteId);
        $newPasswordToken = $this->_mathRandom->getUniqueHash();
        $this->_accountmanagement->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($customer, $newPasswordToken);
        return $newPasswordToken;
    }
}
```

> Here you need to call createCustomer($data, $websiteId, $emailTemplate) function where $data has customer data, $websiteId is website id and $emailTemplate is our custom email template name.